# Automate Tomcat's classpath in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, ant

Someone in my dev team asked if there's a way to set the Tomcat's classpath in Eclipse by Ant.
Everyone is tired to set Tomcat's classpath manually when they switch to another branch in their workbench.

Therefore, we're looking for something that we can use to automatically set the classpath what would be less time consuming.

Do you know something which can be used to achieve this (Ant of maybe some Eclipse plugin)?
I didn't found anything of this subject on the internet.

Comment: What are you changing the CLASSPATHs from and to? When you publish a web project to the server, it is automatically included in the CLASSPATH.

Comment: We need to add some resource and configuration files to Tomcat's classpath. Currently, we're doing this manually using Eclipse. We want to find a way to automate this by using some plugin or maybe (if possible) with ANT. It would be nice to run a target in ANT that sets Tomcat's classpath the way we're doing now with Eclipse.

Comment: Under the Tomcat settings _JVM Settings_ section in Eclipse --> Window --> Preferences you can 'Create a launch Configuration' (button under the _Don't run Tomcat in debug mode_ checkbox - if you do this, then rename the created launch configuration to something sensible related to the 'branch' you are on, and go through the same process for n branches does this achieve what you need?  You can then access the various Tomcat launches from the debug launch configuration drop-down, rather that the Tomcat launch button.  It's not an Ant solution but should provide enough flexibility.